# Flask Odd Behavior w/ Folder Creation/File Uploading

Tags: python, flask, indico

I'll preface this by saying I'm very new to Flask (this being my first project) and I'm interested in hacking it together, rather than best practice.

I currently have code that fails to create folders named by the user in the pictures directory.  I've tried searching for some answers here already but to no avail can I get all 3 of these things to work in harmony.  This is the function in question.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            foo = request.form.get('name')
            if not os.path.exists("/pictures/directory"): os.makedirs("/pictures"+foo)
            app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = "/pictures" + foo
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    else:
        return render_template("upload.html")
    return render_template("index.html")
```

If anyone is interested in also taking a look at why upload.html renders first (which is expected) but the "Continue" button fails to render index.html, I'd be very appreciative.

Here's the repo if anyone's curious about the rest of it: https://bitbucket.org/dillon9/ss

EDIT 1: Thanks to both of you I have a semi-functional frontend and a fully functional backend.  New code is pushed.  Wish I could accept both of your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `foo` variable doesn't hold the value that your user has given. You first get the name that your user specified with

```
foo = request.form.get('name')
```

But then you immediately assign something else to the same variable before using it

```
foo = "/directory/"
```

Edit: Right now your directory is probably being created in C:\ or something. Change your code to something like this

```
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            file = request.files['file']
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                foo = request.form['name']
                path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/pictures/"+foo
                if not os.path.exists(path):          
                    os.makedirs(path)
                app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = path
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        else:
            return render_template("upload.html")
        return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: Haha I completely forgot about leaving this in, that second foo assignment was for debugging to test that folders could actually be created.  Nice catch, I'll edit that

Comment: Are you able to save your picture though?

Comment: Nothing works together, I'm not super worried about the uploading part of it, because it has worked in the past, just not with this current code

Comment: I edited my answer. Seems like you weren't creating your folders inside of your project directory. See if it works now.

Comment: It does work now, thanks so much! Is there a reason that foo = request.form['name'] doesn't get a value and request.form.get('name') returns back a Nonetype object?  Did test with foo = "foo"#foo = request.form['name'] works fine

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get you. Do you mean that request.form['name'] works fine while request.form.get('name') returns a Nonetype?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to change in your code.

**First:**

usually the root page `"/"` is mapped to an `index` named function.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            foo = request.form.get('name')
            if not os.path.exists("/pictures/directory"):
                os.makedirs("/pictures"+foo)
            app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = "/pictures" + foo
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    else:
        return render_template("upload.html")
    return render_template("index.html")
```

**Second:**

it would make more sense to use a single button - in this case `Update` - for updating the content and for redirect then you could discard the `Continue` button.

**Third:**

in your **upload.html** file you have to correct the form code

```
<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
```

to

```
<form action="{{ url_for("index") }}" method= "post" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
```

so you give to the `action` attribute as a value the url of the function which handles this form. And, finally, add the double quotes around the values.